# Read Excel file with python

Tags: python, excel

I will read an excel file with python :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('fichier.xlsx')
print (df.head())
```

I have this error : BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Anyone can help me plz

Comment: Most likely your file has been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your Excel file to ".csv".

Then:

`df = pd.read_csv('fichier.csv')`

Comment: I try to convert it but the same error